# How to create a certain number of buttons in a collection view based on days of the month

Tags: ios, calendar, collectionview

Ok, I am trying to make a simple calendar application for a school project. What I want is to have my CollectionView to be in the layout of a month view calendar. However, I want to create buttons for each day of the given month. So in January, I want the collection view to have 31 buttons and in February, 28 buttons, etc. These buttons will then be linked to another view that shows a calendar in day view. So I want to be able to click on the day 1 button while in for example, January and have it show me Jan. 1 in a day view format.I am new to Xcode and don't really know where to start so any advice on how to approach this is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're making your grid with collection views then you can use the `UICollectionViewDelegate` protocol, and simply use the `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` delegate method to find out which item got selected which is also where you place your view transitioning code.

Comment: Can you by chance provide some example code for what you just described? Thanks

Comment: I would if your question was not as broad otherwise I would practically be making the whole app for you. Lol, im joking, I actually haven't worked with collection views first hand. I suggest you read up on the suggested topics by itself. You'll get there eventually.